# Django: get confused with regroup in template

Tags: django

I have a model Purchase like this:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
   material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
   supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
   amount = models.IntegerField()
   price = models.FloatField()
   state = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In the template, I want to group all the purchases by supplier, so I wrote `<% regroup purchases by supplier as supplier_list %>`, however, the thing I got confused me: I only have two suppliers in database, but got 3 groups here, and two of them is the same supplier.

Testing case:

purchase_purchase table

```
id |  material_id | supplier_id | amount

1  |  3           | 3           | 2
2  |  4           | 3           | 10
3  |  3           | 2           | 10
4  |  3           | 3           | 4
```

Are there any mistakes in my snippet? Waiting for suggestions.

Comment: Can you post your template code for displaying the regrouped list?

Comment: I missed the important feature that regroup doesn't order the input. So the input with same grouper will be separated if they are not consecutive. Anway, thank you a lot.  @fmhr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure that your data is already sorted by the value you are regrouping on.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) for the regroup tag does explain this:

> Note that `{% regroup %}` does not order its input! Our example relies on the fact that the cities list was ordered by country in the first place. If the cities list did not order its members by country, the regrouping would naively display more than one group for a single country.

Comment: Yes, I found this feature in later testing. I should read the doc more carefully, thank you a lot.